# Testing SKPaymentTransactionObserver with StoreKitConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, skpaymenttransaction

I'm using `UIKit` & want to test the use of offer codes.

I have implemented the methods for `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` & I have added & removed my observer in `UIApplicationDelegate`.

The problem I am facing is that none of the `StoreKit` methods get called when using the `presentCodeRedemptionSheet`.

Has anyone found a way to verify that you get the proper transaction data (receipt) when using an offer code?